# RegEx (replace all non numeric characters and enfore 2 decimal place numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, currency

I currently working on some regex logic to enforce the input of field to ONLY accept (replace/display) a number (no alpha characters) and enforce a 2 decimal place limit...

I"m not sure how I can make this more efficient, and also add in the (max) 2 decimal place limit/restriction?

Here is my current on keyup() function

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){

    var valid = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value);
    val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log('bad character found');

        //strip out commas
        this.value = val.replace(/,/g , "");

        //strip out all non-numeric characters (leaving decimal)
        //this.value = val.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, "");
        this.value = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

        //enforce only (max) 2 decimal places
    }   
});
```

I was originally using this, but it is FLAWED (if you go back and add in a comma into the current/existing number, it removes the last digit/character in the field.. (even though that is not the offending character)

```
var valid = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value);
val = this.value;

if(!valid){
    //console.log("Invalid input!");
    this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
}
```

To be clear...

The value DOES NOT have to have a decimal, and forced 2 digits after said decimal point.. but if there IS one.. I need to enforce a 2 character limit after decimal point..

- no commas (at all)
- only allow 1 decimal/period
- while a decimal it not -required-.. if present, ensure there is only 2 decimal places after the period

**update 1:**

ok.. so I have things 'close' (although one line of REGEX would be nice!)

My last 'to-do' item.. is to somehow enforce (if there is a 'dot'... that it only has 2 decimal places after it..... although a dot/decimal is -not- required)

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value);
    val = this.value;
    console.log("ORIGINAL VAL: " + val);

    if(!valid){
        console.log('bad character found');

        var dotCheck = val.indexOf("..");
        if(dotCheck >= 0){
            console.log('DOT CHECK: ' + dotCheck);
            console.log("PRE VAL: " + val);
            val = val.replace("..", "?");
            console.log("POST VAL: " + val);
        }       

        //strip out commas                      
        val = val.replace(/,/g , "");                           
        console.log("AFTER COMMA VAL: " + val);

        //strip out all non-numeric characters (leaving decimal)
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        console.log("AFTER CHAR VAL: " + val);

        //output to field
        this.value = val;

    }

});
```

**update final:**
(final working solution)... still checking out the regex solution posted below...

- no commas
- no characters outside of digits/numbers
- no double '..' (dots)
- no more than 2 digits after decimal point

  ```
  $("#amount").on("keyup", function(){                            
      var valid = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value);
  val = this.value;

  if(!valid){
      var dotCheck = val.indexOf("..");
      if(dotCheck >= 0){                              
          val = val.replace("..", ".");
      }

      //strip out commas                                          
      val = val.replace(/,/g , "");                           

      //strip out all non-numeric characters (leaving decimal)                            
      val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

      //enforce 2 decimal places (max)                    
      var totalLength = val.length;
      var only2DecimalsCount = val.indexOf(".");

      if(only2DecimalsCount >= 0 && totalLength > (only2DecimalsCount + 2)){                          
          val = val.substring(0, (only2DecimalsCount + 3));
      }                           

      //output to field
      this.value = val;                           
  }


  });
  ```

EDIT:   I found that this does NOT handle something likeL

1.9.9  (bummer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your final edit... I added a line to check for the situation: 1.2.3 and replace it with a pattern to remove the second dot. Did it without a look behind because it may not be supported. Here is the line: `val = val.replace(/(\.)(.)(\.)/g, ".$2");` The `".$2"` will replace the .#. with a dot and the pattern group that is the wildcard (.) in this case. Your other check at the bottom will catch a double dot ".." situation.

```
$("#amount").on("keyup", function () {
    var valid = /^\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value);
    val = this.value;
    console.log("ORIGINAL VAL: " + val);

    if (!valid) {
        var dotCheck = val.indexOf("..");
        if (dotCheck >= 0) {
            val = val.replace("..", ".");
        }

        val = val.replace(/(\.)(.)(\.)/g, ".$2");

        //strip out commas                                          
        val = val.replace(/,/g, "");

        //strip out all non-numeric characters (leaving decimal)                            
        val = val.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

        //enforce 2 decimal places (max)                    
        var totalLength = val.length;
        var only2DecimalsCount = val.indexOf(".");

        if (only2DecimalsCount >= 0 && totalLength > (only2DecimalsCount + 2)) {
            val = val.substring(0, (only2DecimalsCount + 3));
        }

        //output to field
        this.value = val;
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Fixed new line by adding parenthesis. Explanation: Parenthesis "groups" the pieces of the pattern together (1-based index). So the new linehas 3 groups - `(\.)- 1, (.)- 2, (\.)- 3`. Replacing with `$2` will call group #2 which in this case is the wildcard.

Comment: Odd results using that new line of yours.. is there a reason WHY it would 'alter' (round up/down/increment) the digit before the second 'dot'?  Example.. I type 1.8.  (and when the second dot happens. the 8 becomes a '2'?)   WTH?  LOL

Comment: It's ignoring the $ sign. So it's always 1.2. I'm looking at how to fix this in js

Comment: Missed parenthesis to make them groups. Editing answer now.

Comment: Sold!  Seems to be working so far by just adding it my current line up!  Thanks!  I'll play around and see if I can break it.. but for now.. "ACCEPTED ANSWER"!

Comment: Great. I'll keep an eye out for you to break it. Good luck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're fine with the order you're doing your processing. Make sure you are re-using your `val` variable. The code above will set `val` equal to `this.value`, but then after each pattern you are setting your replace to `this.value` instead of re-using `val`. You will only see the results of your last replace call.

Your pattern for finding any non-number characters is fine. The only efficiency might be combining it with your comma check by using a logical OR (|) like this:`\d{0,9}(\.\d{0,2})?|,`.

As for enforcing two decimal places, you can use something like this:`(?<=\.[0-9]{2}).+`. This is a positive look behind: `(?<= PATTERN )` and will return matches that have that pattern behind it. Here is a breakdown:

- `(?<=` - Start of Positive Look behind
- `\.[0-9]{2}` - Matches a decimal character ('.') with 2 numbers after it
- `)` - End of Positive Look behind
- `.+` - Anything after the look-behind pattern

You can use this to do a replace with a blank string like you have with the other pattern. If you have only one decimal after the dot (ex: 123.4), it will not be replaced because ".4" will not match the positive look behind. Something like: `this.value = this.value.replace(/(?<=\.[0-9]{2}).+/g, "");`

** Note: Tested patterns on https://regexr.com/ but not in js code

Comment: I also havent been able to get a javascript replace() function to work?

var dotCheck = val.indexOf("..");
       if(dotCheck >= 0){
        console.log('DOT CHECK: ' + dotCheck);
        console.log("PRE VAL: " + val);
        this.value = val.replace("..", "?");
        console.log("POST VAL: " + val);
       }

Comment: Edited my answer. The start of string (^) and end of string ($) characters weren't working in the input field for me. Try removing them and trying again... This worked for me: `val = val.replace(/(?<=\.[0-9]{2}).+/g, "");` ** Tested in js

Comment: ^ Does this replace (no commas, allowing for decimal, but only 1?,...and only 2 digits after decimal?)--- So I'm clear .. this is supposed to replace my edited solution in the original post?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid regexp group  using your above suggested solution

Comment: I had a syntax error in the first pattern of my solution. Edited to fix it. I must have copied it wrong. The last comment is in addition to one of your edits. It will replace anything after a decimal and 2 numbers. Ex: 123.4567 becomes 123.45; 12.34.56 becomes 12.34. Hope this helped.

Comment: They look the same to me? (and still has same syntax error?)  am I missing your updated line or something?

Comment: It is working for me. I am not sure. The positive look behind may not be supported in the browser you're using. I think you're fine with what you have in your edited answer.

Comment: Please see my new answer. I removed the look behind because it may not be supported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188702/discussion-between-dvo-and-whispers).

Answer (score 0):

Try : `^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$`

```
s ='1234567'
/^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/.test(s)
// true

s ='12345.67'
/^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/.test(s)
// true

s ='12345.678'
/^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/.test(s)
// false

s ='123.45.67'
/^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/.test(s)
// false

s ='a12345.67'
/^(\d+)(\.\d{2})?$/.test(s)
// false
```

**Update:** Regex to replace multiple '.' characters

```
s = '123...45'
s.replace(/(\.)+/g, '.')
// '123.45'
```

Comment: I think my TEST portion is fine...no?  (except for maybe not catching multiple dots?? how can I replace them?

Comment: I've added a string replace regex for replacing multiple '.' characters in a string. `s.replace(/(\.)+/g, '.')`

Comment: Thanks.. this is still allowing something like:  '1.8.' to be entered into the field..  (ie: allowing for the second decimal point)

Comment: The regex test I originally posted returns `false` for that test.

Comment: So using my latest updated approach in my OP.. can I add a new line that -DOES- address these multiple, but not right after one another, dot issue?